# express + jade server-side templates with dynamic content vs. caching / 304

Tags: angularjs, express, pug

I have an expressjs app with angularjs on the frontend, and i'm serving jade out of express, i.e.

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

I'm also using jade partials with angular.  The app is based off the [Yeoman angular fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).

*Here's a link to the [navbar.html](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/master/app/views/partials/navbar.html) partial from the generator's demo app for reference (except I am using Jade)*

I inject the current logged in user server-side into the template engine via express middleware to add it to [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.locals) so it is available in the template at runtime, e.g.

```
app.get('/partials/*', function(req, res, next) { 
  res.locals.user = req.user; next(); 
}, index.partials);
```

Now, this app has user roles, let's assume there are two: `['user', 'admin']`, and I wanted to conditionally output the markup from `navbar.jade` depending on the current user's role.

For example, something like this (*admin users should only see admin menu item*):

```
ul.nav
  if user
    li
      a(href='/settings')
  if (user && user.role == 'admin')
    li
      a(href='/admin')
```

I know I can `ng-hide / ng-show` these links cient side with Angular, but I'd prefer to not even output the markup if the user shouldn't have the authorization to use them (they are protected server-side as well.)

So, this approach *kinda* works.  If I login with a normal user, the navbar is fine, then I logout, and re-login as an admin user, but the browser makes a request for navbar.html, and ExpressJS returns a `304 Not Modified`, so the content is stale.  If I refresh/F5, it returns the proper version based on the user's role (i.e. the unbuffered Jade JavaScript is interpreted on the refresh).

I'm trying to figure out how to force it.  I can experiment with cache-control headers and Etag disablement hackery, but I'm trying to resolve a clean way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  The issue was not with Jade/Express -- the problem was with this bit of code:

```
div(ng-include="/partials/navbar")
```

When a user logged out / in, I was mistaken that the browser was issuing a new request for the partial from the server.  Chrome DevTools network tab showed the request with a `304 Not Modified` but on closer inspection, the server was not receiving the request.  To fix it, I now bind the ng-include source attribute to a scope variable, and when the user logs out/in, I refresh the scope variable which forces angular to issue a new request, and Jade/Express execute the template and respond with an updated partial that matches what I expect.